# SQLite ERD ( cost of cast vs union )

Tags: sql, sqlite, casting, union, erd

I have to save lot of (more than 50 000 rows) `document - key - value` in a SQLite database.
My concern is: these values can be textual or numerical (there are dates, strings, numbers, etc).
I have to request my base in 2 ways:

- all values for document ####
- or with comparison operators

I thought about 2 possible solutions:

**solution 1:**
a single table:
`key(text) | type(one of text/date/float) | value(text)`

and using explicit cast when I need comparison (for example,
`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE (CAST(value as float) < "2010-01-01 00:00:00") AND (type='date')`
or
`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE (CAST(value as float) < 17.5) AND (type='float')`

*What I like in this solution*:

- it is easy to get all values for

*What I does not like in this solution*:

- I have to make a lot of (potentially) expensive cast

**solution 2:**
three tables:

- text values : `key(text) | value(text)`
- float values : `key(text) | value(float)`
- date values : `key(text) | value(datetime)`

*What I like in this solution*:

- no more casts

*What i does not like in this solution*:

- getting all values for  has the cost of 3 selects and a union
- I find this less *elegant*

**the question**
So comes the question which of the solutions do you recommend to me? why? do you have another solution to propose?

Comment: `"17.5"` should not have quotes and just read `17.5`.  And the 'date' based example should cast to a DATETIME, rather than a FLOAT.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance. What is MCD?

Comment: Sorry for using the french acronym: MCD stands for "modèle conceptuel de données", the french name of ERM (Entity relationship model)

Comment: It sounds like your data is not organized enough for a single table with anything other than strings in. Indeed, I find it hard to conceive of a useful relation that can only be expressed with all those casts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, storing the value as a string is perfectly acceptable, and the most simple/straightforward, provided that...
- You never have to search based on the value itself (unable to use index)
- You don't process vast (thousands/millions) or records at once

The option of three tables and a `UNION` has a limitation you may not have spotted: the `value` column in the UNIONed view can't be different data-types.  They will either get implicitly cast (based on the type of the field in the first SELECT of the UNION), or the view will simply fail to be created.

My variation on that idea would be to have three value fields in place of one.  You can then add a seperate index for each, have just one table, avoid the need for CASTs and various other benefits.  All at the expense of a little extra complexity in the table (I'd prefer it here rather than the queries using it anyway), but also at a significant increase in space used.

`Key, Type, Value_INT, Value_FLOAT, Value_DATE`

**EDIT:**

Oh, and a last option.  Don't store the values as strings, but store them as floats.  All three data-types that you mentioned can be stored as floats, allowing the use of an Index.

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE (type='date')  AND (value < CAST("2010-01-01 00:00:00" AS FLOAT))`

or

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE (type='float') AND (value < 17.5)`

or

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE (type='int')   AND (value < 17)`

Comment: You're right with the last option, since textual values in a column with _REAL_ affinity should be preserved if I correctly understood [affinity conversions](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity).  
I think I will consider this option seriously :) (doesn't it seems to be a too bloody tricky choice?)